# Scala: using toMap on a Map with a nested Map fails

Tags: scala

In my code, I have the following Map with a nested map defined, I want to fetch this value of the Map (the nested Map) using a function `getTags` which produces the following error:

```
scala> def getTags(tags: Map[String, Map[String, List[String]]]): Map[String, List[String]] = {
     |     tags.map {_._2}.toMap
     | }
<console>:12: error: Cannot prove that Map[String,List[String]] <:< (T, U).
           tags.map {_._2}.toMap
                           ^                                                                        ^
```

I've confirmed that before using the `toMap` function, the error I get is:

```
scala> def getTags(tags: Map[String, Map[String, List[String]]]): Map[String, List[String]] = {
     | tags.map {_._2}
     | }
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Map[String,List[String]]]
 required: Map[String,List[String]]
       tags.map {_._2}
                ^
```

So the type returned before `toMap` is `Iterable[Map[String, List[String]]]`.

How can I get a hold of the `Map[String, List[String]]`?

Appreciate any help on the issue.

Comment: You have a map of maps, which of those inner maps are you trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the return type of your function `Map[String, List[String]]` indicates that you will be returning a single `Map`.  However your function:

```
def getTags(tags: Map[String, Map[String, List[String]]]): Map[String, List[String]] = {
  tags.map(_._2)
}
```

would return many `Maps`, because calling `.map` will return an `Iterable`.  To fix the error you could do something as simple as:

```
def getTags(tags: Map[String, Map[String, List[String]]]): Map[String, List[String]] = {
  tags.map(_._2).head
}
```

But this might not be what your logic should be, and would also throw an exception if the map was empty.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the `toList` function as was also recommended by Hari in order to return many maps and base my logic based on that.

Comment: Did you change the return type of your function?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the Map() to toList, this might help you

Comment: Some more information in your answer would be beneficial.